# Get the range of a nested string according to the original string

Tags: swift

If the string is "hello 111abc222 world", and we have the range of "abc" according to "111abc222", how can we get this range according to the original string "hello 111abc222 world"?

My code works well, but is there a simple way to do it?

```
extension String {
    
    func originalRange(of range: Range<String.Index>, secondStringRange: Range<String.Index>, originalString: String) -> Range<String.Index> {
        
        let distance1 = self.utf8.distance(from: self.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
        let start = originalString.index(secondStringRange.lowerBound, offsetBy: distance1)

        let distance2 = self.utf8.distance(from: range.lowerBound, to: range.upperBound)
        let end = originalString.index(start, offsetBy: distance2)
        
        return start..<end
    }
    
}


let str2 =  "111abc222"
let str = "hello \(str2) world"

let secondStringRange = str.range(of: str2)!
let abcRangeInStr2 = str2.range(of: "abc")!

let abcRangeInOriginalStr = str2.originalRange(of: abcRangeInStr2, secondStringRange: secondStringRange, originalString: str)
print(str[abcRangeInOriginalStr]) //abc
```

[image]

Comment: Is `str.range(of: "abc")` – getting the range directly from the original string – not an option?

Comment: no, this is a simple example, my goal is to transform any range in a string to the original one in the string that contains this string

Answer (score 1):

As asked, your code is pretty close, though it's buggy. If you change `"111abc222"` to `"111你好222"` and search for `"你好"`, you'll get the wrong result. Your mistake is adding `.utf8` in your offsets:

```
let distance1 = self.distance(from: self.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
                    ^ remove `.utf8` here.
```

That said, messing around with raw indexes across different Strings this way is a recipe for bugs. Instead I would recommend working within a single String (the message), and slice out Substrings. Then all the indexes will be compatible. For example:

```
// A convenience that returns substrings rather than ranges
extension String {
    func find(_ needle: some StringProtocol) -> Substring? {
        guard let range = firstRange(of: needle) else { return nil }
        return self[range]
    }
}

// A token embedded in a message
let token = "111你好222"
let message = "hello \(token) world"

// Pull the token back out of the message as a Substring
let tokenSubstr = message.find(token)!

// Search inside the token
let needleRange = tokenSubstr.firstRange(of: "你好")!

// The resulting range is compatible with the whole String.
tokenSubstr[needleRange]  // "你好"
message[needleRange]      // "你好"
```

Of course, your entire design relies on being able to reliably find the token in the message after its been constructed. That can introduce problems if the the strings are arbitrary or complex. You may want to consider keeping track of the entire structure using an [ExpressibleByStringInterpolation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebystringinterpolation#) type, so that you don't have to re-search for the tokens. If that seems useful to you, see [OSLogMessage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/oslogmessage#) for a fairly advanced example. When you pass an OSLogMessage, the `\(...)` substitutions are kept intact, and aren't evaluated until much later (if ever).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about this wrong. If you want to find a substring in a larger string, find a smaller substring in that initial substring, and finally get the range of the string in the original string, you should search in the combined string. Consider this rewrite of your code:

```
let str2 =  "111abc222"
let str = "hello \(str2) world"

if let str2Range = str.range(of: str2) { //If we find "111abc222" in the long string
    let subString2 = str[str2Range] // Create a substring of str that contains "111abc222"
    if let abcRange = subString2.range(of: "abc") { //If we can find "abc" in the substring...
        // print that found range in the original, long string.
        print(str[abcRange])
    }
}
```

That code works because a substring is actually a reference to a range of characters in the original string.

---

Alternately, you can work with ranges within ranges rather than using substrings:

```
let str2 =  "111abc222"
let str = "hello \(str2) world"

if let str2Range = str.range(of: str2) {
    if let abcRange1 = str.range(of: "abc", options: [], range: str2Range) {
        print(str[abcRange1])
    }
}
```

Both approaches will search inside the "111abc222" part of the sting for the "abc" substring, and give the same result. (They would not match an occurrence of "abc" outside of the "111abc222" substring.)